# Membership -Turn Renewal Reminders Off (only for certain contacts)

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders, auto-renew

We are having a handful of members who we don't want to send auto renewal reminders to. Our board or other other staff are in regular contact with them and auto generated renewal reminders are adding confusion.

Has anyone been in the same situation or does know a work around to disable auto renewal reminders, but only for a few contacts (organizations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you A Davidson and Peter for your ideas. After doing some more digging (did not find this post before), I came across [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4301/can-i-remove-specific-emails-contacts-from-scheduled-reminders?rq=1), explaining how to limit the recipients of a scheduled reminder to a defined group.

I think this option will work for us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting there privacy preferences to 'do not email' on the contact page?

Comment: This would be an option, but would it not also block them then from receiving newsletters, etc?

Comment: We have a no bulk emails option, do you have that option? You may be able to customise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work but you could perhaps create a special membership type, then put the relevant contacts in that type.  Then when you edit the Scheduled Reminders entity, omit that new membership type from the selection options.  The reminders would then only go to the memberships you have selected.